# $p\Bbb Z + x\Bbb Z[x]$ is a prime/maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\Bbb Z$ : ring of integers, $p$ : a prime number.

I know that $p\Bbb Z + x\Bbb Z[x]$ is an ideal. But how can I check if it is a prime/maximal ideal?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Let $I$ be the ideal in question. What is
$\mathbb{Z}[X]/ I$? Is it an integral domain? Is it a field?